# MS Access SQL: Using SELECT INTO with a UNION ALL query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010, union-all, select-into

I'm attempting to turn an already working `UNION` query into a `SELECT INTO` as part of a `VBA` procedure for a bunch of temp tables. I'm doing this because Access is having performance issues.

When I try to run this query with the `INTO` clauses inserted, I get this error:

```
"An action query cannot be used as a row source."
```

I'm not entirely sure why I can't execute it or how to get around it without creating more queries. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
C.[CUSTOMER CODE], 
D.[FISCAL DAY], 
D.[TY INVOICE DATE] AS [Invoice Date], 
C.[CUSTOMER CODE]&" - "&D.[FISCAL DAY] AS CONCAT, 
IIF(D.[TY INVOICE DATE] Is Not Null, 'TY', Null) As TYLY

***INTO [FD CUST Missing- Temp]***

FROM [QR- CUST FD] AS C,
[QR- FD SALES] AS D) AS A

LEFT JOIN [QR- CUST FD] AS C
ON C.[FD CONCAT] = A.[CONCAT]
WHERE C.[FD CONCAT] Is Null

UNION ALL 

SELECT DISTINCT 
A.*

***INTO [FD Cust Missing- Temp]***

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
C.[CUSTOMER CODE],
D.[FISCAL DAY],
D.[LY INVOICE DATE] AS [Invoice Date], 
C.[CUSTOMER CODE]&" - "&D.[FISCAL DAY] AS CONCAT, 
IIF(D.[LY INVOICE DATE] Is Not Null, 'LY', Null) As TYLY

FROM [QR- CUST FD] AS C,
[QR- FD SALES] AS D)  AS A

LEFT JOIN [QR- CUST FD] AS C
ON C.[FD CONCAT] = A.[CONCAT]
WHERE C.[FD CONCAT] IS NULL

;
```

Comment: @HansUp I'm not entirely sure I know what you're asking but the base data that the queries come from do not contain any fields with combo boxes or list boxes.

Comment: Oops!  Now I see.  You have 2 `SELECT INTO` statements which you're attempting to combine with a `UNION`.  No dice!  Make both plain `SELECT` statements and use `INTO` with the result set of the top-level `SELECT`  I'm not positive Access will accept even that, but try it first.

Comment: @HansUp It came up with the same error when placing the INTO in front of the first FROM clause :(

Comment: i'm not sure what you expect. a `select into` is something without any output, so what exactly should access do with the union?

Comment: @Aツ Can you elaborate more? I'd like to just keep the query as it is now instead of breaking it up into two different queries just to `SELECT INTO` then `INSERT INTO` where I could do it in the `UNION` of the two. Maybe I'm not getting something with regards to the functionality.

Comment: `select into` is the basicly the same as  `insert into`. there is nothing what could be used to do a uinion, you'll see if you run the query without the second part (and without the union of course). i have really no idea whats the purpose of your query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the error

> An action query cannot be used as a row source.

because a `SELECT ... INTO NewTableName FROM ...` query is an *action query* (like an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE query) which does not return a result set. Therefore the `UNION ALL` has nothing to work with. So, for example, this won't work (resulting in the above error message):

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT LastName 
    INTO Foo 
    FROM Clients 
    WHERE LastName LIKE 'D*'
UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT LastName 
    INTO Foo 
    FROM Clients 
    WHERE LastName LIKE 'T*'
```

However, you can reorganize that query as follows, which does work:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO Foo
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT LastName 
        FROM Clients 
        WHERE LastName LIKE 'D*'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT LastName 
        FROM Clients 
        WHERE LastName LIKE 'T*'
    )
```